# Logging strategy for XBAP Application

Tags: c#, logging, xbap

We have a WPF Application that runs from both desktop and as a XBAP application.For the desktop application log4net based logging is provided.Now the thing is that log4net may not work on the XBAP version.So I am looking for some possible solution for logging.Has anyone done anything in the area? Suggestion are welcome.I'm looking for something simple if possible.I already have a AOP framework.

I plan to check if my app is xbap

```
if (System.Windows.Interop.BrowserInteropHelper.IsBrowserHosted) {
{Do some kinda smart logging that works with xbap?}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your question that your not using FullTrust mode.  So, can you not use Log4Net or nLog and push to a WCF service?

Comment: I am using full trust and i have log4net but how to push log and how to write log ? xbap = cache folder my logging to log file...